# R: Correctly Specifying Constraints in a Function

Tags: r, function, optimization

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data:

```
library(GA)
library(dplyr)

var_1 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
var_2 = rnorm(1000,5,5)
var_3 = rnorm(1000, 1,1)
goal = rnorm(1000,100,100)

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal)
```

I wrote the following function that randomly splits this data into 3 different groups and evaluates a "fitness value" ("total_mean") of these groups based on the percentage of the data within each group that is less than some randomly assigned percentile:

```
#define fitness function
fitness <- function(x) {

x1 = x[1]
x2 = x[2]
x3 = x[3]
x4 = x[4]
x5 = x[5]
x6 = x[6]
x7 = x[7]
x8 = x[8]
x9 = x[9]

    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- my_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(var_1 <= x1 & var_2 <= x2 & var_3 <= x3, "a", ifelse( var_1 <= x4 &  var_2  <= x5 & var_3 <= x6, "b", "c")))
   
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
   
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal, cat)
   
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal, cat)
   
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
       select(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal, cat)
   
    x7 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    x8 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    x9 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
   
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
   
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(goal, prob = x7)))
   
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(goal, prob = x8)))
   
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(goal, prob = x9)))
   
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$goal,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$goal,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$goal,1,0)
   
    #group all tables
   
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
# calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    total_mean = mean(final_table$diff)

n_row_a = nrow(table_a)
n_row_b = nrow(table_b)
n_row_c = nrow(table_c)

return(total_mean)


}
```

I was able to then optimize this function using the Genetic Algorithm in R:

```
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued",
         fitness = fitness,
         lower = c(min(var_1), min(var_2), min(var_3), min(var_1), min(var_2), min(var_3), 0,0,0), upper = c(max(var_1), max(var_2), max(var_3), max(var_1), max(var_2), max(var_3), 1,1,1),
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 10, run = 10)
```

**My Question:** I would now like to add some "constraints" to this function that prevents the arguments of this function from taking certain values and also prevents the splits made by this function having 0 rows. My logic being that these constraints will work by assigning the returned value of the function as "NaN":

```
if (n_row_a < 1 | n_row_b < 1 | n_row_c <1 | x4 < x1 | x5 < x2 | x6 < x3){

total_mean <- NaN

}
```

I tried to add these constraints to the above function:

```
#define fitness function
fitness <- function(x) {

x1 = x[1]
x2 = x[2]
x3 = x[3]
x4 = x[4]
x5 = x[5]
x6 = x[6]
x7 = x[7]
x8 = x[8]
x9 = x[9]

    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- my_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(var_1 <= x1 & var_2 <= x2 & var_3 <= x3, "a", ifelse( var_1 <= x4 &  var_2  <= x5 & var_3 <= x6, "b", "c")))


   
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
   
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal, cat)
   
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal, cat)
   
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
       select(var_1, var_2, var_3, goal, cat)
   
    x7 =  runif(1,0, 1)
    x8 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
    x9 =  runif(1, 0, 1)
   
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
   
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(goal, prob = x7)))
   
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(goal, prob = x8)))
   
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(goal, prob = x9)))
   
   
   
   
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger tha the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$goal,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$goal,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$goal,1,0)
   
    #group all tables
   
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
# calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    total_mean = mean(final_table$diff)

n_row_a = nrow(table_a)
n_row_b = nrow(table_b)
n_row_c = nrow(table_c)



if (n_row_a < 1 | n_row_b < 1 | n_row_c <1 | x4 < x1 | x5 < x2 | x6 < x3){

total_mean <- NaN

}
   return(total_mean)
}
```

**My Problem:** However, now the constraints do not seem to be respected:

```
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued",
         fitness = fitness,
         lower = c(min(var_1), min(var_2), min(var_3), min(var_1), min(var_2), min(var_3), 0,0,0), upper = c(max(var_1), max(var_2), max(var_3), max(var_1), max(var_2), max(var_3), 1,1,1),
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)

# output

> GA@solution
     x1   x2  x3 x4 x5   x6   x7   x8   x9
[1,] 24 -5.3 4.4 38 12 -1.6 0.88 0.23 0.99
[2,] 21 -5.3 4.4 38 12 -1.6 0.88 0.23 0.99
```

As we can see here, X6 is less than X3 - it appears that these constraints were not respected. These solutions should have never been returned.

**Can someone please show me how to correctly specify these constraints in my function?**

**Note:** You can check to see whether all the solutions obey the constraints at once:

```
test = data.frame(GA@population)

test$constraint = ifelse(test$X4 > test$X1 & test$X5 > test$X2 & test$X6 > test$X3, "YES", "NO")

table(test$constraint)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first issue is your function. When you put input after the call to `return`, it is ignored. You can think of `return` as "stop here."

Comment: @ Kat: Thank you for this advice! I now made sure that "return" is the last command in the function, but the constraints are still not being obeyed. Thank you so much!

Comment: May be just penalize the results you want to avoid `if (n_row_a < 1 | n_row_b < 1 | n_row_c <1 | x4 < x1 | x5 < x2 | x6 < x3){

total_mean <-  -1000*abs(total_mean)

} ` (if ga maximises, otherwise remove the minus ..)

Comment: you should add description what your function is supposed to do because it is not clear at all

Comment: @ det: the function is meant to identify 3 "cubes" within the data (cat = a, b,c). the first cube is defined by boundaries x1,x2 ; the second cube is defined by boundaries x3,x4; and the third cube is defined by boundaries x5, x6.  Once these 3 cubes have been defined, for each of these cubes we generate a random number between 0 and 1 - this number serves as a percentile (x7,x8,x9). For each cube, we then want to see what percent of the data is less than the corresponding percentile. This average percentage is what is being returned by the function.

Comment: I want to use the genetic algorithm to pick x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9 such that this average percentage is minimized. Does that make sense? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand background of this problem, but there are few things you could improve and few you need to fix.

**fitness function**

```
fitness <- function(x, var_data, goal){
  
  # points
  x1 <- x[1:3]
  x2 <- x[4:6]
  x3 <- x[7:9]
  
  # constraint 1
  if(any(x1 > x2)) return(-Inf) 
  
  # grouping vector
  split_var <- apply(
    X = var_data,
    MARGIN = 1, 
    FUN = function(y) if(all(y <= x1)) "a" else if (all(y <= x2)) "b" else "c"
  )

  # constraint 2 
  if(length(unique(split_var)) < 3) return(-Inf) 
  
  # for each group percentage of values that are lower than given quantile
  value <- mapply(
    FUN = function(x, y) mean(x < quantile(x, prob = y)),
    split(goal, split_var), x3
  )
  
  # final fitness value
  - mean(value) # minus because of minimization
}
```

You can adapt your goal of fitness function somewhat easier and faster. You **shoudn't** sample for x7,x8,x9 because those are your parameters and you change them randomly within fitness function. Also you are not calculating average percentage (you don't calculate percentages for each group). Keep in mind that this can be extremely biased towards creating many small groups and one big. Because `GA::ga` performs maximization you need to multiply by -1 to get minimization process.

**optimization call**

```
# var data matrix
var_data <- cbind(var_1, var_2, var_3)
# column ranges
limits <- apply(var_data, 2, range)

GA <- ga(
  type = "real-valued",
  fitness = fitness,
  lower = c(rep(limits[1,], 2), 0, 0, 0), 
  upper = c(rep(limits[2,], 2), 1, 1, 1),
  popSize = 50, 
  maxiter = 1000, 
  run = 50,
  var_data = var_data,
  goal = goal
)
```